# Animate activity while showing a fragment using Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation

I have a scenario in which from an activity, on the click of a button, I need to show a fragment with sliding in from right to left and similarly when I press back fragment slides back to the right and shows my previous activity from which the fragment was added.

Now my issue is that the animation to the fragment itself works but I need to animate the activity by sliding out to the left while the fragment is sliding in from the right.

Tried using overridePendingTransition method to do this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_in_from_left, R.anim.push_out_to_left);
```

I tried putting the pending transition in the methods available with the activity onResume, onPause, etc. but didn't get it to work. Following is the code I am using:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_in_from_left, R.anim.push_out_to_left); 
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_from_left, R.anim.push_out_to_left, R.anim.pull_in_from_left, R.anim.push_out_to_left);
transaction.add(R.id.events_holder, myFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("myFragment");
transaction.commit();
```

Tried to put the pending transition on the click of the button as well, before I start doing the fragment transaction things, but didn't work either.

It would be really helpful if anybody can suggest a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't overriding any animation, sliding in a fragment should not move the layout of the activity if you are doing it right. Instead you have to apply an animation which you can define in an xml to the layout containing your activity. In essence you will give the appearance your activity slides out, and fragment slides in. Depending on what target you are building for, after you apply the animation you may need to actually move (in this case applying an animation doesnt actually change the physical location of the layout, it will simply render where you tell it.) the layout containing the fragment. You dont need to physically move the layout containing the activity, because if you specify an empty onclick listener for the bottom layer layout in the fragment no clicks will fall through. When you are done, use another xml animation file to slide the fragment and Activity layout back the way they were (so an opposite animation) and then physically move the fragment back out of the way, or it will still receive all of the on click events. (I do believe this issue has been fixed if you are targeting a new sdk)

an animation xml looks something like this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the big picture. Will try out your suggestion.